# How to do a timeout for the child process after 5 seconds it's running (the child does exec)

Tags: c, timeout

As part of homework, I need to make a child process which runs an .out file
And set timeout of it of 5 seconds
The Child Process does an exec and I want to know how to know
if the child process did timeout or exited normally in the parent process
which is waiting for it to finish.

I found online the setrlimit function for setting the timeout
of 5 secs on the RLIMIT_CPU and it worked but there was no way
of checking if the Child Process timed out or not

I also tried to do a while loop with waitpid of NOHANG
and used time() function to check if 5 seconds past
but the problem was that it isn't really 5 seconds that the child process
runned in them but 5 seconds in real time.Therefore, in one computer it worked fine but in other it timed out for processes which didn't really run for 5 seconds but less.

thx a lot for the help!

here is the code for the rlimit:

```
struct rlimit limit = {5, 5};
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit);
        if (execvp(outFilePath, argv) == -1) {
            return ERROR_OCCURED;
        }
```

and the wait:

```
while (TRUE /*&& currentTime - start < 5*/) {
            if (waitpid(newPid, &newStatus, WNOHANG) != -1) {
                if (WIFSIGNALED(newStatus)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (WIFEXITED(newStatus)) {
                    hasTimeOut = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (errno == ECHILD) {
                    hasTimeOut = FALSE;
                    break;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            sleep(0);
            //currentTime = time(NULL);
        }
```

and I set the hasTimeout before the while to TRUE

Comment: If it hits the hard limit it is killed with `SIGKILL` that you can catch with `wait*`. Assume that if the process killed itself it did time out.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thx for the help. Is there a way to force the rlimit do the hard limit and not the soft limit?

Comment: There are two limits: hard and soft. So you'd set them both to the same value - i.e. `rlimit_cur = rlimit_max = 5`. And do remember that this is *CPU time*, not wall clock time.

Comment: that's what I have done and checked it with WIFSIGNALED by the way I have checked the status the waitpid returned and it's the same for both timeout and not timeout `struct rlimit limit = {5, 5};
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit);
        if (execvp(outFilePath, argv) == -1) {
            return ERROR_OCCURED;
        }`

Comment: then you should provide the code you're using for waiting.

Comment: and the checking `if (waitpid(newPid, &newStatus, WNOHANG) != -1) {
                if (WIFSIGNALED(newStatus)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (WIFEXITED(newStatus)) {
                    hasTimeOut = FALSE;
                    break;
                }`

Comment: `waitpid` can return `EINTR` in which case you need to retry

Comment: I did set the hasTimeOut to TRUE outside and thx for the EINTR

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not running the `ECHILD` case by mistake :D

Comment: I did it in case the waitpid misses the exit of the child process but this can wait I prefer solving the main problem xD

Comment: I mean how do you know *which* branch did it take? Did you add a debug print to all these branches?

Comment: Notice that you must set both the hard and soft limits!

Comment: I used CLion Debugger and saw that the status returned was always 0 both for not timed out and timed out (of course in not timed out it depends on the .out file)

Comment: Aha now I get it, you're using `WNOHANG` - if `WNOHANG` is specified, 0 is returned in case no child has exited and you must not inspect the status.

Comment: so to what should I change it?

Comment: run strace or similar to find out what's happening